# Beware - this riddle might kill you!

Tags: riddle, word

The answer to this riddle is a single word. It should be slightly harder than my simultaneously posted [Riddle with a twist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5604/riddle-with-a-twist), but still fairly easy.

*From the middle of the sun through all the rain, 

Colours stretch from money to money. 

Between the end of life and the start of death, 

The first part of me resides.*

*Now you need to pick sides, 

But keep away from the twin snakes. 

I am the weapon the other side lacks, 

And by now you should know what I am.*

Comment: Is that an MGS reference?

Comment: @dmg - What's MGS? (So the answer is probably 'no'.)

Comment: Metal Gear Solid.

Comment: A great riddle! I like how seamlessly the wordplay and metaphor blends in with the meaning-based clues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is

> cyanide

From the middle of the sun through all the rain,
Colours stretch from money to money.

> Refers to the rainbow, as has been previously noted.

Between the end of life and the start of death,
The first part of me resides.

> The color cyan lies between green (life) and blue (death) in the rainbow's spectrum.

Now you need to pick sides,
But keep away from the twin snakes.

> As others have noted, this refers to stripping the two Ss from "sides", leaving "ide".  Cyan + ide = cyanide

I am the weapon the other side lacks,
And by now you should know what I am.

> Hydrogen cyanide has been used as a chemical weapon, which is why the riddle might kill you.

Comment: I like your thoughts on getting cyan, but I'm not quite sure how blue equates to death very well. Certainly a great attempt though I think.

Comment: There's the blue screen of death.  And, not to be indelicate, the pale blue hue of a body.

Comment: Ah! The blue screen of death. I like it.

Comment: You got it! I was thinking of "between the end of life and the beginning of death" as meaning between D and E, the 4th and 5th letters of the alphabet, which correspond to green and blue, the 4th and 5th colours of ROYGBIV ... but maybe that was a bit too obscure!

Comment: Wow. Amazing riddle (truth be told) but that part about D and E... oh man, that was seriously twisted of you :)

Comment: @GarciaHurtado - huehuehue (and thanks) :-)

Answer (score 8):

From the middle of the sun through all the rain, 
Colours stretch from money to money.

> Refers to a rainbow going from pot of gold to pot of gold.

Between the end of life and the start of death, 
The first part of me resides.

> end of lif**e**. start of **d**eath. first part of me (**r**ainbow) resides. We have collected R,E and D. RED.

Now you need to pick sides,

> SIDES

But keep away from the twin snakes.

> Remove SS = IDE

I am the weapon the other side lacks,

> L

And by now you should know what I am.

> We take the letters we have accumulated: RED IDE L

You are a:

> RIDDLE :D

From the title:

this riddle might kill you!

> LYNCH MOB!!

Comment: Dammit, I figured out the start too, but couldn't handle the second part. Congratulations.

Comment: @Victor I have intel that it's wrong. Keep going :)

Comment: *Some* of this is right but not all. The final answer is wrong (you have two E's not one!). I think I shouldn't say any more.

Comment: Why is "L" the "weapon the other side lacks"?

Comment: @Joe Other side... left vs right perhaps. light vs darkness. still trying to solidify. sorry, this answer is wrong :(

Comment: end of life and beginning of death is f?

Comment: @JamesRyan I'm afraid I don't follow

Comment: "Between the end of life and the start of death,  The first part of me resides." = and ? (Life and death)

Comment: If 'r' is between 'e' and 'd', it should be 'ERD' not 'RED'.  But that assumes "me" refers to "rainbow," when I believe it refers to the word we're looking for.  I think @BmyGuest had it, and the word is supposed to start with "AND"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I don't think it's AND... it's not this riddler's style :p

Comment: 'cop, you were almost there except for the 'red' bit. You just got the wrong ... got the wrong ... wrong ... huehuehue! :->

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer may be:

> Lightning

Beware - this riddle might kill you!

> Lightning can kill people.

From the middle of the sun through all the rain,

> Light comes from the sun.

Colours stretch from money to money.

> This refers to a rainbow, with pots of gold on each end.  Light can be broken up into the spectrum of colors in a rainbow.

Between the end of life and the start of death,

> People supposed see a white light as they die.

The first part of me resides.

> That means the first part of the word is "light".

Now you need to pick sides,

> One side is the sky, the other side is the ground.

But keep away from the twin snakes.

> I'm not sure about this, each "n" in lightning could be considered a snake.

I am the weapon the other side lacks,

> Lightning only comes from the sky, not the ground.

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't fit very well with the second verse, or with "rain" in the first. +1 anyway. (Why should the ground be the 'other' side?)

Comment: Lightning does actually come from the ground as well. Nowhere near as big, but as the bolt comes down to earth, a small lightning bolt goes up from the earth to meet it

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> Idea

From the middle of the sun through all the rain, 
Colours stretch from money to money.

> Red herring (like in his other riddle)

Between the end of life and the start of death, 
The first part of me resides.

> Part of the word is comprised of letters at the end of the word "life", and/or the beginning of the word "death", in this case "dea"

Now you need to pick sides, 
But keep away from the twin snakes.

> Take the word "sides", and remove the "snakes" to get "ide" (thanks to d'alar'cop for this one)

I am the weapon the other side lacks,

> The other side here is our "dea" from earlier, literally lacking the letter "i" from "ide".

And by now you should know what I am.

> Idea?!
>  Not sure how the title of this riddle relates though