# Riddle with a twist

Tags: riddle, word

This is a riddle with a twist. Almost all the lines will point you in the right direction, but hidden somewhere in the riddle is a red herring. If you find the right solution, I'll accept your answer, but if you find the red herring *and* the right solution, I'll upvote and accept. Don't be afraid; the puzzle is still really easy. Good luck!

*From the middle of the sun through all the rain, 

Colours stretch from money to money. 

The very first part of this, 

Gives you my first word.*

*Not him, not it, perhaps his wife? 

Or half of either of his parents? 

Add to that the precious thing, 

Not the three, the seven, or the nine, 

To get at last my second word.*

**Who or what am I?**

Comment: "Not the three, the seven, or the nine" possible hint to LOTR?

Comment: @AzzieRogers - You deserve a sandwich my friend! :-) Does it fit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> a red herring

Explanation:

```
From the middle of the sun through all the rain,
```

> The red herring line; doesn't affect the answer.

```
Colours stretch from money to money. 
The very first part of this, 
Gives you my first word.
```

> "This" refers to the previous line itself. The very first part of the line is "colours", which, when combined with the rest of the answer, naturally yields RED.

Or, alternatively, thanks to @dmg:

> Could refer to a rainbow. "Money to money" meaning the pot of gold at the end of a rainbow. And the first part of the rainbow is red.

```
Not him, not it, perhaps his wife?
Or half of either of his parents?
```

> HER (Not him or it, half of motHER or fatHER)

```
Add to that the precious thing, 
Not the three, the seven, or the nine, 
To get at last my second word.
```

> RING (Lord of the Rings reference)

Comment: I knew this one was too easy... Well done!

Comment: "hidden somewhere in the riddle is a red herring." - don't forget that one :p

Comment: Red is the first colour of the rainbow. That is how you can get red :)

Comment: @dmg - Aha! So you're not too set on the LotR solution? :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I like both solutions. Roger has a valid theory, might as well help him with the final touch. I still am supporting my theory though.

Comment: I didn't say there was a red herring *line*! There's only one red herring in the riddle, and you've found it, Roger. The first line refers to the formation of a rainbow, as @dmg realised.

Comment: @randal'thor I did think the wording there was suspicious.

Comment: @Roger - Feel free to call in a lynch mob; that's what d'alar'cop does when someone writes the answer in an innocuous way in the preface :->

Answer (score 3):

My guess is

> The one ring

Breakdown:

> From the middle of the sun through all the rain, - **Middle**earth reference
> Colours stretch from money to money. - actually, not the red herring. Reference to different sorts of rings
> The very first part of this, - **the** is the very first part
> Gives you my first word.
> Not him, not it, perhaps his wife?
> Or half of either of his parents?
> Add to that the precious thing, - **precious**
> Not the three, the seven, or the nine, - **more LOTR**
> To get at last my second word.

And the herring is

> Not him, not it, perhaps his wife?
> Or half of either of his parents?

Comment: Well done for cracking lines 7-8, but how does your answer fit any of the other lines?

Comment: @randal'thor updated my answer